# Scala regex find/replace with additional formatting

Tags: regex, scala, regex-group

I'm trying to replace parts of a string that contains what should be dates, but which are possibly in an impermissible format.  Specifically, all of the dates are in the form "mm/dd/YYYY" and they need to be in the form "YYYY-mm-dd".  One caveat is that the original dates may not *exactly* be in the mm/dd/YYYY format; some are like "5/6/2015".  For example, if

```
val x = "where date >= '05/06/2017'"
```

then

```
x.replaceAll("'([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{4})'", "'$3-$1-$2'")
```

performs the desired replacement (returns "2017-05-06"), but for

```
val y = "where date >= '5/6/2017'"
```

this does not return the desired replacement (returns "2017-5-6" -- for me, an invalid representation).  With the Joda Time wrapper `nscala-time`, I've tried capturing the dates and then reformatting them:

```
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._
import org.joda.time.DateTime

val f = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
y.replaceAll("'([0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4})'",
   "'"+f.print(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy").parseDateTime("$1"))+"'")
```

But this fails with a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "$1"`.  I've also tried using the `f` interpolator and padding with 0s, but it doesn't seem to like that either.

Are you not able to do additional processing on the captured groups (`$1`, etc.) inside the `replaceAll`?  If not, how else can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$1` like backreferences can only be used inside string replacement patterns. In your code, `"$1"` is not a backreference any longer.

You may use a "callback" with [`replaceAllIn`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/matching/Regex.html) to actually get the match object and access its groups to further manipulate them:

```
val pattern = "'([0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4})'".r
y = pattern replaceAllIn (y, m => "'"+f.print(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy").parseDateTime(m.group(1)))+"'")
```

Answer (score 1):

[Regex.replaceAllIn](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/matching/Regex.html) is overloaded and can take a Match => String.